# Use FlightAware API in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, wsdl, android-ksoap2

**Overview:**
Hello. I'm trying to get flight data (flight paths and whatnot) using the FlightAware api in Android. I'm unsure what the best way to go about accomplishing this is. I should mention that I do have a valid username and api key. I'm using Android Studio.

To get a better idea of what kind of information I'm looking for, you can take a look at their JavaScript [example](http://flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/). Here's a picture of an HTML page (their JavaScript example) that allows for the visual representation of a flight path on a map using data from the FlightAware api:
[https://i.gyazo.com/ab7bb4560e698ae00dc9ef9a52eca64c.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL1Gc.jpg). I have a way to visually represent the data in my app; I just need a way to acquire the data in the first place (in Android).

**Question:** So with that in mind, how can I query for flight information like you see in the example above in Android?

**Unsuccessful Attempts:** If you head over to the code example section of the FlightAware site, you can view the many proposed ways to implement their api. Naturally I scrolled down to the Java section since Android uses a sizable portion of Java. I then tried to implement the NetBeans example in Android. The problem is, I'm not sure how to use the WSDL (never even heard of WSDL before) link they provided in Android Studio. I gathered that it's just XML that can be converted into Java classes? I tried using WSDL2Code (website) to convert the WSDL into Java classes I could use; this worked to some extent but could not convert *all* of the classes I need (still missing some). I then tried the Android plugin EasyWSDL generator (free version), but that generated even less Java classes than WSDL2Code. Finally, I went into the NetBeans IDE and generated the Java classes from the WSDL link and was able to generate all of the Java classes. But, they don't seem to work in Android, because the Java classes generated via NetBeans tend to import `javax.xml.bind.annotation` which doesn't seem to be included in Android.

Here's an example of one of the generated Java classes I copied over from NetBeans:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
/**
 * <p>Java class for EnrouteRequest complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="EnrouteRequest">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="airport" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="howMany" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
 *         &lt;element name="filter" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="offset" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "EnrouteRequest", propOrder = {
    "airport",
    "howMany",
    "filter",
    "offset"
})
public class EnrouteRequest {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String airport;
    protected int howMany;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String filter;
    protected int offset;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the airport property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getAirport() {
        return airport;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the airport property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setAirport(String value) {
        this.airport = value;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I seemed to have found a working solution using ksoap2:

1). Add the ksoap2 library to your libs folder. You can find that [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/k/Downloadksoap2androidassembly252jarwithdependenciesjar.htm). 
2). Make a new thread. 
3). Inside that thread input the following code:

```
MarshalBase64 mbase = new MarshalBase64();
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("howMany", howMany);
request.addProperty("airport", airport);
request.addProperty("filter", "");
request.addProperty("offset", 0);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.bodyOut = request;
envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2003;
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
String n = "";
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);
ht.debug = true;
try {
     mbase.register(envelope);
     ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
     SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Explanation:

- `NAMESPACE` is "http://flightxml.flightaware.com/soap/FlightXML2".
- `METHOD_NAME` is the name of the method you're calling, "EnrouteRequest" in my case.
- `mbase` is used to serialize the byte array.
- `request.addProperty` is used to add arguments. In my case, there were four parameters for that particular method.
- `response` is the returned object you'll be dealing with. This is the information the method you're calling will return based on given arguments.

**Important note**! 
You must authenticate before executing the code above or you will not have access to the FlightAware API. You can authenticate with the following code (replace `User` with your username and `APIKEY` with your API key):

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("User",
                        "APIKEY".toCharArray());
            }
        });
```